# Can't see what I'm typing in Sketch

Tags: fonts, sketch-app

Every time I type something, I can't see what I'm typing. It's always white with no fill.. Even if I set the font color to black, I still can't see my text when editing it.
[image: when typing new text, i can't see what i'm typing]

[image: I can't see what I typed unless I select it]

Comment: Is it in a mask?

Comment: @OwenHughes No there's no masks

Comment: Are you sure that the part you're editing has no fill if you only select this part ?

Comment: @Clafou Sry, not entirely sure if I understand you correctly, but even if I turn on fill color, the text is still white while i'm typing/editing. It's not until I click outside the text to quit editing that the text becomes black.

Comment: Do you have this issue with every sketch file or is it tied to a specific document?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm a Sketch beginner and this happened to me as well. I've realised the text colour and fills are different things. I had this setting on for my text and it was behaving exactly as you described:

[image]

Once I changed that to something other than white I could see it again while typing!

Comment: That fixed it!! You're my hero.

Comment: Yes! thank you this worked! You are a lifesaver, it was becoming time consuming to correct the color every time.